# Conditional formatting for email lists?

Tags: conditional

I am new to SharePoint coding and am wondering if there is any type of conditional formatting which will allow there to be an email sent to a specific group when a certain drop-down is selected. For example, if someone was to input a new item in my list and select Level 1, it would email all the people on that list. Ideally I would like to be able to filter out who gets emailed by what is selected when the new item is being added.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve in a couple of steps. Below is an example which you can refer for your requirement.

1. Create a workflow variable for `emailRecipients` and `emailSubject`.
2. Add IF conditions and check your field value matches to your condition and set workflow variable. Then the flow will look like as follows.

[image]

**How to set `emailRecipients` variable with people of group field in your current item.

[image]

**How to set workflow variables for email action**

[image]

*Note: If you want conditional email body then you can create a one more workflow variable like `emailBody` and set the value same as `emailSubject`.*